# How to target a video element when there are multiple video files. But also hide that elements play button and listen for when the video ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to add an event listener on multiple videos and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have multiple videos on my page and when the video ends, it has to load the video to be played again, display the replay button and hide the controls. This is the code I have so far. If anyone could please help me find out how to set an eventlistener for 'ended' on a specific video being watched. I would really appreciate it!

**HTML**

```
    <div class="video-container">
              <video class="vidDJ" width="100%" preload="none">
                <source src="video1.mp4"
                  type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="vidText">
                <div class="playBtn"></div>
                <div class="replayBtn"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- vidText -->
            </div>
            <!-- video-container -->

            <div class="video-container">
              <video class="vidDJ" width="100%" preload="none">
                <source src="video2.mp4"
                  type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="vidText">
                <div class="playBtn"></div>
                <div class="replayBtn"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- vidText -->
            </div>
            <!-- video-container -->

           <div class="video-container">
              <video class="vidDJ" width="100%" preload="none">
                <source src="video3.mp4"
                  type="video/mp4">
              </video>
              <div class="vidText">
                <div class="playBtn"></div>
                <div class="replayBtn"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- vidText -->
            </div>
            <!-- video-container -->
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video = document.getElementsByClassNames("vidDJ");

    $(".playBtn").click(function() {
      var video = $(this).closest(".video-container").find("video")[0];
      video.play();
      $(this).hide();

      $("video").on("click", function() {
        video.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
        $("video").click(function() {
          this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();
        });
      });
      return false;
    });

    video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      video.load();
      $(".replayBtn").show();
      $(".playBtn").hide();
      $(".vidText").show();
    });
```

I know the eventlistener I have is garbage but I was trying everything. I remember reading about possibly using querySelectorAll for the video elements and looping over them and THEN adding the event listener but I'm still pretty new to js/jQuery and can't remember how. Any help would be appreciated.

This is a function that adds a replay button and reloads the video when the video finishes. It works by selecting a video based on its id. My problem is using one addeventlistener function for all videos

```
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
      video.load();
      $(".replayBtn").show();
      $(".playBtn").hide();
      $(".vidText").show();
    });
```

Comment: None of your elements has an id, let alone an id which is equal to `"vidDJ"`. Otherwise, it's not really clear what is your intent, but indeed what you do with these nested event listeners doesn't sound good.

Comment: Ok I edited my post to change the #vidDJ to .vidDJ as my issue is using one event listener to select any video element. I added a function at the bottom that shows how i can get one video to do what i want targeting it's id.